# Interface to unite calculate methods with different primitive paramter types

Tags: java

I have two types of objects that can perform a calculate() operation with either an `int` or a `byte`:

```
public class A  {
  public int calculate(int n) {...}
}
```

and

```
public class B  {
  public byte calculate(byte n) {...}
}
```

I want to have an `ArrayList` of objects that I can loop over calling the calculate method.

How do I do that, using an interface?

Considering the difference in the int/byte signature

Would something like this be a good approach?

```
public interface Calculatable {
    int calculate(int number);
    default byte calculate(byte number) {
        return (byte) calculate((int) number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it an option to use [`java.lang.Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) instead?

Comment: @Program How would it be used? 3 interfaces - one for Number parameter, the other two for  `byte` and `int`, calling `byteValue` and `intValue` respectively?

Comment: Maybe you can use something like `public interface Calculatable<T extends Number>()` with a method of `T calculate (T number);`. Maybe you can elaborate a little bit more on what you are trying to do and what the problem/issue is you have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a 3-rd class and check based on type could be useful

```
public class TestCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
        l.add(Integer.valueOf(300));
        l.add(Byte.valueOf("120"));
        l.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
        TestCalc tc = new TestCalc();
        ComputeAB cab = tc.new ComputeAB();
        for (Object o : l) {
            System.out.println(cab.calculate(o) + ":" + cab.type);
        }
    }

    class A {
        public int calculate(int n) {
            return n;
        }
    }

    class B {
        public byte calculate(byte n) {
            return n;
        }
    }

    class ComputeAB {
        String type = "";

        public Object calculate(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof Integer) {
                type = "int";
                return new A().calculate((int) o);
            }
            type = "byte";
            return new B().calculate((byte) o);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
300:int
120:byte
1:int
```